# How to get unique values from foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to get unique values in a drop down list. Code for drop down is:

```
@foreach($admin_bills as $admin_bill)
   <?php $month = date('M, Y', strtotime($admin_bill->created_at)); ?>
   <option value="{{ $admin_bill->id }}">{{ $month }}</option>
@endforeach
```

This gives me all the values based on `created_at`. For example, if there are multiple entries on same month, it gives me results like

```
Aug, 2017
Aug, 2017
Aug, 2017
Sep, 2017
Sep, 2017
```

But if there are multiple entries on same month, I want them to show once in the drop down. So the result will be like:

```
Aug, 2017
Sep, 2017
```

I cannot simply use function like `array_unique()` here and the `$admin_bill->id` should get the first id of unique `$month`. How can I do that? Please help. I am using Laravel 5.4

Thank you.

Comment: Would it not be easier to do this in the controller before passing it to the view?

Comment: You can use array for it, like if you want to unique value than store value in array check array if value exists in array than skip that statement else statement will run.

Comment: @OptimusCrime, you are right. Let me try in controller. I will need methods like distinct, right? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Ahsan If you move the logic into the controller, you can reuse the data you have already fetched. It will just need a simple `in_array` lookup. See my answer.

Comment: use $adminBillUnique =  $admin_bills->unique(); but $admin_bills should be a collection!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended that you solve this in the controller. Not in the view. In the controller you can write something like the following:

```
$admin_bills->pluck('created_at')->map->format('M, Y')->distinct();
```

I didn't test this but I think it will get you in the right direction.

I am assuming that the `created_at` property is automatically parsed to a carbon object. Because that is the way Laravel normally works.

Comment: Giving me error `Method distinct does not exist.` Any suggestion?

Comment: Oh sorry. It should be `unique()`. `distinct()` is for database stuff

Comment: Your solution is working, I just had to add ID. Thank you. Final code: `$admin_bills->pluck('created_at', 'id')->map->format('M, Y')->unique();` in controller and in view `@foreach($unique as $id => $value)
                                            <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                                    @endforeach`

Answer (score 1):

If you move this logic into the controller, you can do it with a simple loop:

```
$uniques = [];
foreach ($admin_bills as $bills) {
    $month = date('M, Y', strtotime($bills->created_at));
    if (!in_array($month, $uniques)) {
        $uniques[] = [
            'date' => $month,
            'id' => $bills->id
        ];
    }
}

// Useage
foreach ($uniques as $v) {
    $v['id']
    $v['date']
}
```

Comment: It's giving me unique values for month, thank you. But how can I associate it with this: `<option value="{{ $admin_bill->id }}">`? Because its passing only month in $uniques...

Comment: @Ahsan That depends on what you want. According to your code, there is no directly link between [month, year] and the ID. The ID is unique for every admin bill. Now that we use unique [month, year], there is no relationship between the IDs and the label anymore. You could use the first ID for the first [month, year] pair, but I can't see how that makes any sense. Do you see?

Comment: This is where I am stuck at this point. ID has no direct relation with unique months, but I nee the ID because this actually connects with another table and I cannot leave it

Comment: @Ahsan Well, again. I don't know how the unique months relates to the other table. It depends on how the rest of your application is structured. It is impossible to answer with the information provided here.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being able to make it clearer. Actually I am getting unique months for visual purpose only, making it easier to select the option. But ID is the actual value saved in table, as you can see ID is the option value field here.

Comment: What you ask is not possible of there is a `1 <=> 1` relationship between [month, year] and a given ID if that ID is used for something later.

Comment: I think your answer is very close to a solution. We just need to pass the id in addition to created_at in the $uniques array

Comment: @Ahsan I have updated the code as you suggest, but I belive this will cause other problems for you.

Comment: I tried this way but you are right. It caused me other problems. But thank you so much taking time into helping me. I learned new things. It will help me in future. The solution from Mark Walet is working... Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting it in your controller:

```
    $admin_bills_formated = $admin_bills->map(function ($item, $key) {
        $item->month = Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->month;
          return $item;
    });

    $admin_bills_grouped = admin_bills_formated->groupBy('month');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `admin_bills` variable is a collection and `created_at` field is a `Carbon` instance.

In your controller

```
$adminBillUniqueMonths = $adminBills->unique(function($bill) {
    $bill->created_at->format('Ym');
});
```

and in your view

```
@foreach($adminBillUniqueMonths as $bill)
   <option value="{{ $bill->id }}">{{ $bill->created_at->format('M, Y') }}</option>
@endforeach
```